# How to cross-platform converting char* to long long (64-bit)?

Tags: c++, parsing, cross-platform, long-long

How can I convert a char* string to long long (64-bit) integer?

I use MSVC and GCC compilers and my platforms are Windows, Linux and MAC OS.

Thanks.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<long long>(str)`

Comment: Of course, this assuming `long long` exists on that platform? (The C++ standard doesn't define that type) :)

Comment: But I don't want to use boost library. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Billy: long long already supported by GCC and MSVC.

Comment: @Amir: That does not mean it is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strtoull` for unsigned long long or `strtoll` for signed long long. On any Unix (Linux, Mac OS X), type `man strtoull` or `man strtoll` to get its description. Since both are part of the C99 standard they should be available on any system that supports C. The Linux man pages also [have examples on how to use them](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll).

Comment: 1. The question is tagged C++. 2. Not there on Windows.

Comment: Is `stoull` the equivalent to `strtoull` on Windows?

Comment: 1. Since he wants to convert a C string, I was assuming a C function would be just fine. 2. That is a problem of course... someone should file a bug report with MS, it's a C99 function.

Comment: @Simon C: Similar, but not the same.

Comment: MS claims that strtoll is not a C++ function and provides their own extension called `_strtoi64`.

Comment: @Simon C: stoull is portable, but only defined for C++11. It is similar to strtoull. The main difference is the use of exceptions.

Comment: I use `strtoll`, `wcstoll`, `strtoull`, `wcstoull` and define these names as a macro in Windows. In windows `_strtoi64`, `_wcstoi64`, `_strtoui64`, `_wcstoui64` are the same functions but different names.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ with a compiler that supports `long long int`, I would use a `std::istringstream` object.  For instance:

```
char* number_string;
//...code that initializes number_string

std::istringstream input_stream(number_string);
long long int i64_bit_type;
input_stream >> i64_bit_type;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
long long int i;

if(sscanf(string, "%lld", &i) == 1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`boost::lexical_cast` is probably the simplest (in code). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm for more info. Alternately use a `stringstream` to parse out the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

 char serial[1000];

 long long var = _atoi64(serial);
```